# Node Kafka Streams hangs after first connection

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, node-kafka-streams

I have an HTTP2 application which creates a new Kafka streams producer and sends messages to it on receiving a message from an incoming stream.

The first time it connects and functions properly. On subsequent streams, it fails without throwing any sort of error.

This is how I'm doing it:

```
"use strict";

const {KafkaStreams} = require('kafka-streams');
const {nativeConfig: config} = require("./kafka-config.js");

const kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(config);
const stream = kafkaStreams.getKStream(null);

...stream stuff...
stream.to("test-topic");

await stream.start()

await stream.writeToStream("my message");

await setTimeout(kafkaStreams.closeAll.bind(kafkaStreams), 100););
```

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: What is `kafkaStreams.getKStream(null)`? What is `stream.writeToStream("my message")`?

Comment: I'm guessing that it is this that he means: https://github.com/nodefluent the question shouldn't be tagged with kafka-streams since they don't have much to do with each other. @Boris K what do you mean by subsequent streams?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa yes, exactly.

What I mean is that all of the above stuff runs on a route in a server. The first request runs fine, and on subsequent requests, it hangs on ```await stream.start()```